# Html e-mail banner image resized in Outlook for android - Mailchimp

Tags: outlook, html-email, mailchimp, email-templates

I made a custom html e-mail template for mailchimp. It contains repeatable blocks that can be added in the classic campaign editor. All e-mail clients are going well except Outlook for android.

I have 3 variations of content blocks:

1. **Banner + Tekst** (Banner full width, Text below banner full width)
2. **Product + Product** (2 columns each half the width)
3. **Banner Only** (same as 1, but without the textfield)

Now on Outlook for android, if we add the Product + Product block the image of the banner blocks Banner + Tekst and Banner Only will be resized to like 55% of the full width. If we place only the banner blocks the images are full width.

I tried multiple options like fixed 600px width (the full width of the mail) and a lot of others, spend more than 6 hours now to fix it but still no change.

[image]

**The CONTENTBLOKS 1, 2 and 3.**
(Below jsfiddle with complete template)

```
                        <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" id="templateBody" width="600">
                          


                            <!-- BEGIN CONTENTBLOK 01 // -->
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="contentbloks" mc:variant="Banner + Text">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="banner-img" width="100%" colspan="2">

                                        <img src="https://richterio.nl/gw/promo-image.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="600" style="max-width:600px;width:600px;margin:0;padding:0;" height="300" class="templateImage" mc:label="Promo_Image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" mc:hideable mc:edit="promo_image_1">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" class="contentblok_1_text_column" width="100%">

                                      <!-- BEGIN MODULE: BODY CONTENT // -->
                                      
                                      
                                      <div mc:hideable mc:edit="body_content">
                                          <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                                          <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                                          <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                                          <h4>Heading 4</h4>
                                          <p><strong>Getting started!</strong><br>To choose your fonts, colors, and styles, click <strong>Edit Design</strong> at the bottom of this screen. After you create a look and feel you love, click inside this box to start adding your own content.</p>
                                          <p>Any time you create a layout here, you'll be able to find it in the <strong>Saved Templates</strong> tab on the <strong>Templates</strong> step. Then, you can reuse it as-is or quickly create new, similar versions for different types of messages.</p>
                                          <p>Our <a href="https://templates.mailchimp.com/">Email Design Reference</a> can help you add content blocks to this template or show you how to design and code your own from scratch.</p>
                                        <!-- Button CTA // -->
                                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="btn_cont green" valign="middle"><a href="https://www.gezondheidswinkel.nl/" target="_blank">Bekijk actie</a></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        <!-- // Button CTA -->
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- // END MODULE: BODY CONTENT -->

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            <!-- // END CONTENTBLOK 01 -->
                            <!-- BEGIN CONTENTBLOK 02 // -->
                            
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="contentbloks" mc:variant="Product + Product">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" class="column1" style="max-width:282px;min-width:282px;" width="282">

                                    <!-- BEGIN MODULE: PRODUCT CONTENT 02 PART 1 // -->
                                    
                                    <div mc:hideable mc:edit="product_content_2_p1">
                                    <table class="product_title" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="282">
                                        <tr><td class="pad12 blue-light">
                                            <h2>Gezond &amp; Wel</h2>
                                            <h1>Cranberry detox booster</h1>
                                            <p>Goed voor de gal- en leverfunctie</p>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                
                                    <img src="https://richterio.nl/gw/product_blue.jpg" width="282" style="max-width:282px;width:282px;" class="templateImage" mc:label="Product Image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" mc:edit="product_image_2_p1">
                                    <div mc:hideable mc:edit="body_content_2_p1">
                                        <table class="promo" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="282">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad12 blue">
                                                    <center>
                                                        <table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="line-height:35px">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <h2>KORTING</h2>
                                                        <table class="discount-s" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="line-height:35px">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <!-- Old Price/New Price 1 // -->
                                                                <tr><td>
                                                                    <strong>Hello world 500g 
                                                                            <span class="oldprice">
                                                                                22.50
                                                                            </span>
                                                                    </strong>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <!-- // Old Price/New Price 1 -->
                                                                <!-- Old Price/New Price 2 // -->
                                                                <tr><td>
                                                                    <strong>
                                                                        Hello world 500g 
                                                                            <span class="oldprice">
                                                                                22.50
                                                                            </span>
                                                                    </strong>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <!-- // Old Price/New Price 2 -->
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- Button CTA // -->
                                                        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td align="center" class="btn_cont pink" valign="middle"><a href="https://www.gezondheidswinkel.nl/" target="_blank">Bekijk actie</a></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // Button CTA -->
                                                    </center>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <!-- // END PRODUCT: PRODUCT CONTENT 02 PART 1 -->

                                  </td>
                                  <td valign="top" class="column2" style="max-width:282px;min-width:282px;" width="282">

                                       <!-- BEGIN MODULE: PRODUCT CONTENT 02 PART 2 // -->
                                    
                                    <div mc:edit="product_content_2_p2">
                                    <table class="product_title" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="282">
                                        <tr><td class="pad12 green-light">
                                            <h2>Gezond &amp; Wel</h2>
                                            <h1>Cranberry detox booster</h1>
                                            <p>Goed voor de gal- en leverfunctie</p>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                
                                    <img src="https://richterio.nl/gw/product_green.jpg" width="282" style="max-width:282px;width:282px;" class="templateImage" mc:label="Product Image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" mc:edit="product_image_2_p2">
                                    <div mc:hideable mc:edit="body_content_2_p2">
                                        <table class="promo" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="282">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pad12 green">
                                                    <center>
                                                        <table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="line-height:35px">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <h2>KORTING</h2>
                                                        <table class="discount-s" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="line-height:35px">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <!-- Old Price/New Price 1 // -->
                                                                <tr><td>
                                                                    <strong>Hello world 500g 
                                                                            <span class="oldprice">
                                                                                22.50
                                                                            </span>
                                                                    </strong>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <!-- // Old Price/New Price 1 -->
                                                                <!-- Old Price/New Price 2 // -->
                                                                <tr><td>
                                                                    <strong>
                                                                        Hello world 500g 
                                                                            <span class="oldprice">
                                                                                22.50
                                                                            </span>
                                                                    </strong>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td class="discount"><strong>18</strong></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_decimal"><strong>50</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="discount_dot"><strong>.</strong></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <!-- // Old Price/New Price 2 -->
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                         <!-- Button CTA // -->
                                                        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td align="center" class="btn_cont pink" valign="middle"><a href="https://www.gezondheidswinkel.nl/" target="_blank">Bekijk actie</a></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // Button CTA -->
                                                    </center>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <!-- // END PRODUCT: PRODUCT CONTENT 02 PART 2 -->

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>



                            <!-- // END CONTENTBLOK 02 --> 



                            <!-- BEGIN CONTENTBLOK 03 // -->

                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="contentbloks" mc:variant="Banner Only">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="banner-img" width="600">

                                        <img src="https://richterio.nl/gw/promo-image.jpg" width="600" style="max-width:600px;width:600px;margin:0;padding:0;" height="300" class="templateImage" mc:label="Promo_Image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" mc:hideable mc:edit="promo_image_1">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            <!-- // END CONTENTBLOK 03 --> 



                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

**Full html e-mail template:**
https://jsfiddle.net/1bdrzhLf/

Some of the things i tried:

- Collspan="2" on the td containing the banner img
- Content blok content in more tables
- Width="600" instead of width="100%"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your template is not fully responsive. It still has fixed desktop sizes and layout set in a few places. Mainly:

1. Large images (`logo-header.jpg` and the two `promo-image.jpg`).
2. The two columns.

The first issue can be solved by setting the three images concerned a style of `width:100%; max-width:600px;` (instead of `width:600px; max-width:600px`). I'd also recommend removing the `height` set so the image can scale homothetically.

The second issue can be solved by adding new styles inside a `@media` query targeting the `.column1` and `.column2` classes.

```css
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .column1, .column2 { display:block !important; margin:auto !important; }
}
```

Here’s a full code version based on yours with these few fixes applied: https://parcel.io/e/556fddfc-6a83-4b8f-b3ec-68acf8867fe7?

And here are tests on Email on Acid before and after these fixes:

- [Before](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/ltvNeSjr32lROtHJ9xFoOtKI2Eb2HFmIIWPy942zDxMyO/android12_outlookapp_pixel6_lm/screenshot)
- [After](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/GXUxr3t2p9dvgNHYucXTm54xFrIRGb7t7PhDd1BzIVWw1/android12_outlookapp_pixel6_lm/screenshot)

Comment: Thank you this looks already better. But our wish is to keep the two columns next to each other and not stacked.

Comment: I fixed the not stacking of the column by making the display inline-block in the the '@media (max-width:600px) {
    .column1, .column2 { display:block !important; margin:auto !important; }
}'  only outlook on mobile shows the columns stacked but thats fine.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to reproduce the issue as I wanted to see what was going on in browser with your custom HTML, before I went to that effort. I'm seeing issues with this code not responding when I decrease the screen size.

Debugging the code I can see that your two column structure has fixed widths which aren't being adjusted for smaller screens, so that alone will blow out your template. Table cells/columns will not stack natively.
You could either squeeze these columns or stack them, however I would suggest switching the `<td>` tag to a `<th>` if you want to stack them. This is because Outlook iOS doesn't support stacking `<td>` elements, but doesn't enforce it on `<th>` tags. 
You may need to apply font weight declarations on the text inthese two columns to ensure it doesn't appear bolded which is the natural function of a `<th>` (table header) tag.

I can also see the very top header image doesn't have the 'templateImage' class applied, so that too isn't adjusting for smaller screens. You should also either remove the hardcoded height on the image or adjust/apply another class to auto out the height.

Now, these may not be the root cause alone but fixing those fixed the issues I was seeing in browser, which may potentially fix the issue you originally posted. 
Ultimately, any responsive issues in browser should be fixed first and foremost. If there is an issue there, there will certainly be issues in email clients.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment and i will look in to it. Making it images smaller and stacking columns is not what we want on mobile. So actually it will not be responsive.